# MySQL query to show a persons last 8 sporting results (e.g W, L, or D) from a table

Tags: mysql

The following query:

```
SELECT * FROM `results`
WHERE player1_id = 2 AND community_id = 16
OR player2_id = 2 AND community_id = 16
ORDER BY date
DESC Limit 8
```

produces a results like this (actual db table extends to also show player 2 details also, e.g `player2_id`, `player2_team`, `player2_result`):

**Please note the player can either be player_1 or player_2 depending on if they were the home or away team**

```
 +----------+--------------+------------+--------------+-----------------+
 | result_id| community_id | player1_id | player1_team | player1_result  |
 +----------+--------------+------------+--------------+-----------------+
 |    27    |     16       |     2      |   Chicago    |       W         |
 |    28    |     16       |     2      |   New York   |       W         |
 |    29    |     16       |     2      |       LA     |       L         |
 |    30    |     16       |     2      |   Chicago    |       D         |
 +----------+--------------+------------+--------------+-----------------+
```

I want to run a query to give a list of the last 8 results based on a players, community, and result.

The output i am looking for it:

```
 +----------+------+
 | player results  |
 +----------+------+
 |       W         |
 |       W         |
 |       L         |
 |       D         |
 +-----------------+
```

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like (not tested)

```
SELECT player1_result FROM `results`
WHERE player1_id = 2 AND community_id = 16
UNION
SELECT player2_result FROM `results`
WHERE player2_id = 2 AND community_id = 16
ORDER BY date
DESC Limit 8
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the other posted answer I was able to work out the rest as:

```
SELECT player1_result, date , results_id FROM `results`
WHERE player1_id = 2 AND community_id = 16
UNION ALL
SELECT player2_result, date, results_id FROM `results`
WHERE player2_id = 2 AND community_id = 16
ORDER BY date
DESC
Limit 8
```